# Showing Bessel integral function is solution of $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-n^2)y=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I'm trying to show that $J_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(n\theta - x\sin \theta) d\theta$ is solution for $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-n^2)y=0$.

I try the following:
$$J'_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \sin (n\theta - x\sin \theta)\sin (\theta)\, d\theta$$

and,

\begin{align*}
J_n''(x)&=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(n\theta - x\sin \theta)\sin^2 (\theta)\, d\theta \\
&=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(n\theta - x\sin \theta)(1-\cos ^2\theta) \, d\theta \\
&=-J_n(x)+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(n\theta - x\sin \theta)\cos^2 (\theta)\, d\theta \\
\Rightarrow J_n''(x)+J_n(x)&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(n\theta - x\sin \theta)\cos^2 (\theta)\, d\theta\\
\Rightarrow x^2J_n''(x)+x^2J_n(x)&=\frac{x^2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \cos(n\theta - x\sin \theta)\cos^2 (\theta)\, d\theta
\end{align*}

but I don't know how to continue from here.
How can I continue?.

Comment: I think you must involve integration py part relative to $\theta$ in $J''(x)$

Comment: @EDX Thanks, I did that and it worked.